# Embedding iframe in Wikimedia based Wiki

Tags: html, iframe, wiki

I have been trying to embed an iframe to a wiki page that I'm working on based on wikimedia but not the actual wikipedia without any luck.

I've also tried googling on this topic, but have been fruitless. Will appreciate any advice on this pls.

Thks.

Answer (score 12):

There's the easy way and the slightly harder way.

The easy way assumes you don't have a publicly editable wiki (i.e. non-logged in users cannot edit and creating an account is not automatic).

If that's the case, simply set `$wgRawHtml` to true and you will be able to input any arbitrary HTML into your pages by wrapping it inside the `<html>` tag.

Here's an example:

```
This is '''wikitext'''.

<html>
This is <em>HTML</em>.
</html>
```

Now, if you have a publicly editable wiki you most definitely don't want users to be able to add any and all HTML to your wiki. In that case you can use the [Verbatim extension](http://trac.wikia-code.com/browser/wikia/trunk/extensions/3rdparty/Verbatim). This will embed the contents of a page in the MediaWiki namespace as-is, preserving any HTML markup.

For example:

```
<verbatim>Foo</verbatim>
```

Would embed the contents of MediaWiki:Foo.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Where to set $wgRawHtml to true?

Comment: @dev27 LocalSettings.php

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the [IDisplay extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:IDisplay).

> The iDisplay extension allows MediaWiki pages to embed external web pages. It also allows setting an option to put a blocking page in front of it, so you prevent loading the page until the user wants to load the page.

It's implemented with an `<iframe>`.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: iDisplay : This extension has been archived